# EXCEL or CALC Question: How to set a max number of character in a cell and automatically skip 2 rows when max number of character is reached?

Tags: excel, character, cell, calc

I'm looking for a way to do this in Excel or Calc:

1. Set the maximum count of characters per cell of column D <= 70.
2. If characters count of any cell in column D >= 70, then skip 2 rows.

Explanation:

I want to be able to write text in excel efficiently skipping 2 rows every 70 characters.

Example:

1. In Excel/Calc sheet cell D1, writing short sentences/strings of 70 characters max.
2. When cell D1 characters count >= 70, having  the cursor automatically skip 2 rows (cells D2 and D3).
3. Continue writing/inputing the rest of the sentence/string from cell D1 directly into cell D4.
4. Do the same operations automatically from cell D4 to cell D7, from D7 to D10 etc. for all of column D.

Is this possible in Excel?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possibly through using a data entry form? https://trumpexcel.com/data-entry-form/

Comment: The limitation of char count can be handled with data validation, but skipping 2 rows instantly must be done in VBA. My suggestion: a code in VBA that controls everything you want to do.